# How to convert XML to HTML table?

Tags: php, html, xml

How do I go from this (using PHP preferably):

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

To this (please imagine this to be an actual HTML table, I am not allowed to post images yet):

```
|bookstore|book|    title       |     author        |year|price|
|         |    |Everyday Italian|Giada De Laurentiis|2005|30.00|
|         |    |Learning XML    |Erik T. Ray        |2003|39.95|
```

Please notice that all nodes are listed but only those values are written that have a value. This is like converting the XML into a complete a "flat" table, if you get what I mean.

Comment: You'll need to use something like SimpleXml, then figure it out from there.

Comment: Yeah, but how. I have used every XML parser PHP has. It's about the logic of generating this kind of table.

Comment: IF available XML parsers don't make what you want, your last resort is a bunch of regexp filtering sequentially every line of your file.

Comment: Iterate through the `<book>` items and construct your own HTML. You don't need regex for this.

Comment: Also please do not duplicate your own questions. Instead edit and improve the original one. That's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29465946/367456) which I now closed against the one here.

Comment: Probably related: [How excel reads XML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25992326/367456)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to manipulate the data and just need to present it you can make an [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Bookstore</th>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use php XSLT processor to generate the html or just link to the XSLT directly in the xml. For example if you link it like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bookstore.xsl"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

This is what would be rendered in the web browser:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Bookstore</th>
                <th>Book</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>author</th>
                <th>year</th>
                <th>price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Everyday Italian</td>
                <td>Giada De Laurentiis</td>
                <td>2005</td>
                <td>30.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Learning XML</td>
                <td>Erik T. Ray</td>
                <td>2003</td>
                <td>39.95</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to input XML and generate the table. I can't hard code the XML.

Comment: @AsfandyarHashmi thats exactly what an XSLT does! It does not replace your xml document but transforms it into a different output. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: But I can't hard code anything. It has to be generic. For example, you used title, author etc. I have to derive that from the XML itself.